# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Http\Request::has(), 0 passed

Tags: php, laravel

I have seen many similar questions but most of the answers look complicated and do not seem too similar to my issues. Again, I am new to Laravel and would need the simplest form of explanation.

I want to don't show info in view, show up as long as I searched.

My Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $transactions = UserTransaction::query();
    $userId = request()->get('userId');
    $price = request()->get('price');
    $type = request()->get('type');
    $status = request()->get('status');

    $ordering = request()->get('ordering');
    if($userId){
        $transactions->where('userId' , $userId);
    }
    if ($price) {
        $transactions->where('price' , $price);
    }
    if ($type) {
        $transactions->where('type' , $type);
    }
    if ($status) {
        $transactions->where('status' , $status);
    }

    return view('admin.transaction.index',[
        'transactions' => $transactions->paginate(5)->appends($request->except('page')),
        'stats' => $stats
    ]);
}
```

My Blade

```
@if( $transactions->count() > 0 && request()->has() )
     @foreach($transactions as $transaction)
         {{ $transaction->id }}
         {{ optional($transaction->user)->full_name }}
         {{ $transaction->type }}
      @endforeach
@endif
```

I get this error

[image: error]

Comment: you should pass param to request()->has()  .like request()->has('userId'). In blade @if( $transactions->count() > 0 && request()->has() )

Comment: Check the documentation on how to use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present) on the `Request` object.

Comment: Can I convert `user` to `all`, using Laravel trick?

Comment: what do you mean by _Can I convert user to all_?

Comment: @if( $transactions->count() > 0 && request()->has('all') )

Comment: if no additional condition required then write @if( $transactions->count() )

Comment: I want to don't show info in view, show up as long as I searched.

Comment: if you want to check multiple params in the request object use: $request->has(['userId', 'price', 'type', 'status']) or if just any param is required use hasAny(['userId', 'price', 'type', 'status'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for hiding view until user searched any one field.So you can do the following

```
@if( $transactions->count() > 0 &&collect($request->all())->filter()->isNotEmpty())
```

if you want to ignore page from checking then you can use except

```
collect($request->except('page'))->filter()->isNotEmpty()
```

Better don't execute query until one of the filter value is filled because any way you don't to display it in view

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   
    $userId = request()->get('userId');
    $price = request()->get('price');
    $type = request()->get('type');
    $status = request()->get('status');

    $ordering = request()->get('ordering');
    $transactions=[];
    if(collect($request->all())->filter()->isNotEmpty()){
        
        $transactions = UserTransaction::query();
    if($userId){
        $transactions->where('userId' , $userId);
    }
    if ($price) {
        $transactions->where('price' , $price);
    }
    if ($type) {
        $transactions->where('type' , $type);
    }
    if ($status) {
        $transactions->where('status' , $status);
    }
     $transactions->paginate(5)->appends($request->except('page'))
    }
        
        
    

    return view('admin.transaction.index',[
        'transactions' =>$transactions,
        'stats' => $stats
    ]);
}
```

Also instead of repeating `collect($request->except('page'))->filter()->isNotEmpty()` this in multiple  place ,you can assign to variable in controller

Answer (score 1):

You should check in the controller whether data has been entered or not. If not, then return the null for `$transactions`.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if(count($request->all()) > 0) {
        $transactions = UserTransaction::query();
        $userId = request()->get('userId');
        $price = request()->get('price');
        $type = request()->get('type');
        $status = request()->get('status');

        $ordering = request()->get('ordering');
        if($userId){
            $transactions->where('userId' , $userId);
        }
        if ($price) {
            $transactions->where('price' , $price);
        }
        if ($type) {
            $transactions->where('type' , $type);
        }
        if ($status) {
            $transactions->where('status' , $status);
        }

        $transactions= $transactions->paginate(5)->appends($request->except('page'))
    } else {
        $transactions = null;
    }

    return view('admin.transaction.index',[
        'transactions' => $transactions,
        'stats' => $stats
    ]);
}
```

Then in your view just check `$transactions->count() > 0`